# `media` attribute for `<link rel="icon" ... />` does not work for setting favicon based on 'prefers-color-scheme'

Tags: html, media-queries, favicon

I'm attempting to configure my site to automatically switch between two different favicons - one for light mode, and one for dark mode. I currently have my site configured as follows:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        ...
        <link rel="icon"
              href="/favicon-dark-mode.png"
              type="image/png"
              media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)" />
        <link rel="icon"
              href="/favicon-light-mode.png"
              type="image/png"
              media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)" />
        ...
    </head>
    ...
</html>
```

When testing with Firefox though, the browser always just uses whichever favicon is listed in the page markup last (in this case, the light mode one).

I've verified that the resources linked by the above `<link>` tags are reachable, and that the media query should in-fact be chosen:

```js
window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches  // --> true
```

[MDN seems to suggest this this should work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#media), but perhaps favicon `<link />` instances are an exception to this?

I understand that there are other solutions to this problem in the realm of manually manipulating the DOM in order to update the favicon. That being said, this question is more specifically concerned with whether or not the above code *should* work. So...

Should the above code work?

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<link>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-link-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: @Rob While it is true that no HTML specification has _required_ the 'self closing slash' (and more so that it may be discouraged -- see link), it is not true that it _cannot be used_. In fact, it explicitly provides that it _can_ be used.

See the [HTML5 specification regarding opening tags for void elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#start-tags:void-elements).

Comment: I didn't say it cannot be used. But why would you? The W3C Validator will even flag it. [It carries no meaning](https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Markup-%C2%BB-Void-elements#trailing-slashes-in-void-element-start-tags-do-not-mark-the-start-tags-as-self-closing). It does nothing. And browsers ignore it. If anything, [it can do harm](https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Markup-%C2%BB-Void-elements#trailing-slashes-directly-preceded-by-unquoted-attribute-values). So using it makes no sense at all.

Comment: I've tested with Chrome, Firefox and Safari on mac. Of the three, only Chrome respects the media query when `rel="icon"` (regardless of which media query), while all of them respects it when `rel="stylesheet"`. It seems like it should work like you (and I) expect, but I couldn't find definite proof. Taking it to Mozilla's bugtracker: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1838175